# TypeORM: Relations eager on tree entity

Tags: node.js, tree, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Tree entity like this:

```
@Entity('structures')
@Tree('closure-table')
export class StructureEntity extends AbstractEntity<StructureDto> {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @TreeParent({ onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  parent: StructureEntity;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: StructureEntity[];

  // Eager option for enable eager loading
  @ManyToOne(
    () => OrganizationEntity,
    (organization) => organization.structures, { eager: true },
  )
  organization: OrganizationEntity;

  dtoClass = StructureDto;
}
```

I use `@Tree` decorator with 'closure-table' type which allows me to have tree relation like Parent and Children.

I get trees this way:

```
const structures = await this.structuresRepository.findTrees();
```

I have to use `findTrees()` method without any query builders to get all trees in the database with all their children, children of children, etc.

My problem is that in addition to the parent-children relationship within my table, I have the Many To One relation with Organization entity. It works fine, I can write data into the database with all relation, but when I fetch the data I miss organization property:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-06-11T13:17:16.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-06-11T13:17:54.552Z",
        "name": "Parent",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "createdAt": "2021-06-11T13:54:53.774Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-06-11T13:59:40.997Z",
                "name": "Child",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
}
```

Organization Entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'organizations' })
export class OrganizationEntity extends AbstractEntity<OrganizationDto> {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => StructureEntity, (structure) => structure.organization)
  structures: StructureEntity[];

  dtoClass = OrganizationDto;
}
```

I suspect this is a TypeORM slack, because I can't use eager loading to get data from another table using the tree relation inside my entity. Are there any options for getting all the entity data using the tree structure?

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

I only tested on a tree entity of type materialized path and with a many to many relation. In this situation doing this solved the problem:

```
await getManager().getTreeRepository(StructureEntity).findTrees({ relations: ["organization"] });
```